# Is it good practice for a react component to have returned value of null?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got a portal at the bottom of the screen just for informational purposes. It is displayed on a redux state and this component is at `App` level. Problem is with re-render of the entire parent component if this portal component changes its state. In my case, if someone closes the portal. Here's how I close the portal on a click.

```
dispatch({
  type: 'close-portal',
  payload: {
    portalState: { display: false },
  },
});
```

#### App component

```
const isPortalOpen = useSelector((state) => state.user.portalState.display);
<Switch>
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} exact />
    <Route path='/error' component={PermissionErrorPage} exact />
</Switch>
{isPortalOpen && <InformativeMessage />}
```

Now If I am on the `Login` page and I close the portal, the entire page re-renders.

### Alternative

I removed the conditional rendering from the `App` component and moved that into the `portal` component itself.

#### App component

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} exact />
    <Route path='/error' component={PermissionErrorPage} exact />
</Switch>
<InformativeMessage />
```

#### Portal component

```
return (
  <>
    {isPortalOpen ? (
      <EuiPortal>
        <EuiBottomBar
          style={{
            backgroundColor: showUnsavedWarningPortal ? "red" : "",
            padding: "20px",
          }}
        >
          <EuiFlexItem
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <EuiFlexItem>
              <EuiButtonIcon
                onClick={closePortal}
                color="ghost"
                iconType="crossInACircleFilled"
              />
            </EuiFlexItem>
            <EuiFlexItem style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <EuiText>{message}</EuiText>
            </EuiFlexItem>
          </EuiFlexItem>
        </EuiBottomBar>
      </EuiPortal>
    ) : null}
  </>
);
```

### Doubt

Now this will return `null` if the portal is closed but this component isn't completely removed. If I open up the Dev tools and head over to the Components tab I can able to see the portal component. Of course, there's nothing inside but is it a good practice to have this component through out the entire app is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in returning `null`; [react official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering) uses `null` it in their examples as well.
Also it is specified as valid node type in react; as you can see [react's `@types/react/index.d.ts` type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L231) file:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is nothing wrong with it, and I have seen such technique being used a lot. Preferably, I like first approach more -  it puts the logic in the App component, and the InfoMessage only need to care about its presentation - it is a nice way to do a bit of separation of concern

Comment: I see, Thank you. but here I am trying to reduce the unnecessary re-renders. Cause in my case If I close the message, the page shouldn't be re-render, just the component itself should. is there any other way to achieve this?